variable arithmetic outside of the document environment
I'm trying to fit a text box on the left of the main text. My idea was to define a variable and then define the margin of the main text using \geometry. I also wanted to add some space between the text box and the main text by adding the required width to the variable, but it stops my code from compiling:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % For positioning the Info Box
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % For creating the Info Box with background color and rounded corners
\usepackage{everypage} % To repeat the Info Box on every page
\usepackage{geometry} % For setting page margins
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text (optional)

% Define the width and height of the Info Box
\newcommand{\infoboxwidth}{5cm} % Adjust the width of the Info Box
\newcommand{\infoboxheight}{\textheight} % The height of the Info Box (full page height)

% Define the Info Box environment
\newtcolorbox{infobox}[1][]{colback=gray!20, colframe=black, arc=4mm, boxrule=0.5mm, width=\infoboxwidth, height=\infoboxheight, #1}

% Set the page layout to accommodate the Info Box
\geometry{
    left=\infoboxwidth + 1cm, % Adjust left margin to avoid overlap with Info Box
    right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm
}

\begin{document}

% Add the Info Box to every page
\begin{textblock*}{\infoboxwidth}(0cm,0cm) % Position the box at the top left corner
    \begin{infobox}
        \centering
        % Content of the Info Box
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\infoboxwidth]{photo_cv.png} % Portrait Placeholder
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \textbf{\Large Your Name}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{Coordinates:}\\
        Address, Phone, Email\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textbf{Basic Information:}\\
        Availability, Work Permit, etc.\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textbf{Languages:}\\
        Language 1, Language 2, etc.\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textbf{Diplomas:}\\
        Diploma 1, Diploma 2, etc.\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textbf{Hobbies:}\\
        Hobby 1, Hobby 2, etc.
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{infobox}
\end{textblock*}

% Job Title
\section*{Desired Position Title}

% Introduction
\subsection*{Introduction}
A brief overview of skills, experience, and career objectives.

% Professional Experiences
\subsection*{Professional Experiences}

\textbf{Job Title 1}\\
\textit{Company Name, City} \hfill Start Date - End Date\\
Description of tasks, bullet points, etc.

\textbf{Job Title 2}\\
\textit{Company Name, City} \hfill Start Date - End Date\\
Description of tasks, bullet points, etc.

% Formations (Education)
\subsection*{Formations (Education)}

\textbf{Degree Title 1}\\
\textit{School Name, City} \hfill Start Date - End Date\\
Description of courses/projects.

\textbf{Degree Title 2}\\
\textit{School Name, City} \hfill Start Date - End Date\\
Description of courses/projects.

% Skills
\subsection*{Skills}
Category 1: Skill 1, Skill 2, etc.\\
Category 2: Skill 1, Skill 2, etc.

\end{document}


The culprit is at line 17: left=\infoboxwidth + 1cm
I found several ways to do variable arithmetic inside the document environment, but how do I do it outside of it?
P.S. I have no idea how to tag this correctly.
Edit:
As suggested in the linked post, left=\dimeval{\infoboxwidth + 1cm} works perfectly.
Thank you all very much!

This is unrelated to the document env. You could simply use 6cm as it's a constant known in advance or use left=\dimexpr\infoboxwidth+1cm
